# Using Geekworm UPS HAT while powering the raspberry pi from micro usb?

Tags: pi-3, ups

I recently ordered a Geek-worm UPS HAT Board included with a 2500mah Lithium polymer battery. Can I connect this to my raspberry pi and power it on and then provide power to the raspberry pi through the micro usb port? Will the UPS shutdown automatically? Or will my raspberry pi become fried?

Comment: A URL to the product that your question is about would be nice.

Comment: https://m.banggood.com/Geekworm-UPS-HAT-Board-2500mAh-Lithium-Battery-For-Raspberry-Pi-3-Model-B-Pi-2B-B-A-p-1105260.html

Comment: Isn't the point of the UPS for it to be used in place of the power supply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UPS hat has its own micro USB port and is designed to always provide power, and being charged while providing power.  So you put it on, install the drivers, plug your power supply into the hat and run your pi from it.
In that sense, it is no different than buying a USB charging battery and running the pi from that, and recharging the battery when you are somewhere with a PS.